# iPad4 - issue with select dropdown

Tags: jquery, html, css, ipad

Guys I'm working on a B2B portal as a front end developer. And i'm facing an issue only in iPad4 with a language drop down that looks like this -

[image]

So, there's a main menu and a language dropdown. The language defaults to English. Now the problem here is, when the user changes the language to Hindi for example, and then decides to change it back to English, nothing happens. This is how it shows in iPad(below). Ticks for both English and Hindi

[image]

It's a simple menu and dropdown -

```
<li id="tlb" class="mobile-nav-bg open">
   <a id="currentlanguage" class="fl" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
   <span class="icon-globe fl"></span>English
   </a>
   <span class="fl navspacer"></span>
      <ul id="languagedropdown" class="newdashdrop">
         <li class="top-arrow-black"></li>
         <li>
            <select id="languageslist" onchange="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
            <option value="/User/SetLanguage?language=English" selected="selected"> English </option>
            <option value="/User/SetLanguage?language=Hindi"> Hindi </option>
            <option value="/User/SetLanguage?language=Test Language"> Test Language   </option>
         </select>
         </li>
      </ul>
</li>
```

Any idea what is the problem? Thanks

[Further Investigation here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35884307/selected-selected-doesnt-work-in-safari-browser)

Comment: if nobody is answering here you should try to post your question at http://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @0x594f4c4f203b29 No luck there too mate!